# incorrect output using numpy.where to set wind directions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have some pretty simple Python code where I'm trying to label wind directions as "N", "NE", etc based on the actual direction in degrees.  I am getting some really strange results, and don't know why.

```
dir = np.array([307,45,198,355])

Sixteen_UD = np.empty(len(dir),dtype='str')
Sixteen_UD[np.where(np.logical_or(dir >= 348.75, dir < 11.25))] = "N"
Sixteen_UD[np.where(np.logical_and(dir >= 11.25, dir < 33.75))] = 'NNE'
Sixteen_UD[np.where(np.logical_and(dir >= 33.75, dir < 56.25))] = 'NE'
Sixteen_UD[np.where(np.logical_and(dir >= 56.25, dir < 78.75))] = 'ENE'
Sixteen_UD[np.where(np.logical_and(dir >= 78.75, dir < 101.25))] = 'E'
Sixteen_UD[np.where(np.logical_and(dir >= 101.25, dir < 123.75))] = 'ESE'
Sixteen_UD[np.where(np.logical_and(dir >= 123.75, dir < 146.25))] = 'SE'
Sixteen_UD[np.where(np.logical_and(dir >= 146.25, dir < 168.75))] = 'SSE'
Sixteen_UD[np.where(np.logical_and(dir >= 168.75, dir < 191.25))] = 'S'
Sixteen_UD[np.where(np.logical_and(dir >= 191.25, dir < 213.75))] = 'SSW'
Sixteen_UD[np.where(np.logical_and(dir >= 213.75, dir < 236.25))] = 'SW'
Sixteen_UD[np.where(np.logical_and(dir >= 236.25, dir < 258.75))] = 'WSW'
Sixteen_UD[np.where(np.logical_and(dir >= 258.75, dir < 281.25))] = 'W'
Sixteen_UD[np.where(np.logical_and(dir >= 281.25, dir < 303.75))] = 'WNW'
Sixteen_UD[np.where(np.logical_and(dir >= 303.75, dir < 326.25))] = "NW"
Sixteen_UD[np.where(np.logical_and(dir >= 326.25, dir < 348.75))] = 'NNW'
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
array(['N', 'N', 'S', 'N'], dtype='<U1')
```

It should be:

```
['NW','NE','SSW','N']
```

What is wrong with what I'm doing?

Comment: FYI, `dir` is a built-in name in Python. You shouldn't give things the same name as built-in stuff since it causes the built-in thing to become inaccessible. Just a good habit to form.

Comment: An actual [mre] would be just like `Sixteen_UD[0] = "foobar"` instead.

Comment: @KellyBundy You only know that because you understand the problem.

Comment: @Barmar No, I know because I did a minimal amount of debugging, trying to minimize the example. Not even with some fancy IDE debugging but with prints and using TIO.run, as I'm only on a phone.

Comment: @KellyBundy I think this is a perfectly reasonable MRE. Unless you notice the pattern that the results are all the first letter of the expected result, it's hard to know what's significant. I hope you didn't DV because the example had a few extra lines.

Comment: @Barmar You know that's it's the first letter by printing the array after each assignment and see  the third assignment (with NE) making it `['' 'N' '' 'N']`. Really not hard.

Comment: Note that you can simplify the procedure. If you have an array `['N', 'NE', ...]` of 16 directions, your segment size is `360/16=22.5` degrees. Adding the offset of half a segment, `int((x - 360 + 22.5 / 2) // 22.5)` gives you the index of the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array stores **single characters**:

```
>>> Sixteen_UD.dtype
dtype('<U1')
```

`U` is the [`np.str_` unicode string](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.str_) type, length 1. The output is entirely correct, it's the first letter of the correct directions.

To store *arbitrary-length* strings, use `object` as the dtype:

```
Sixteen_UD = np.empty(len(dir), dtype=object)
```

That'll store any Python object.

You could also state you want to store strings of length 3, explicitly specify a length with the `U[length]` notation. Use `np.zeros()` to fill this array with empty strings:

```
Sixteen_UD = np.zeros(len(dir), dtype='U3')
```

as `np.empty()` *can* lead to somewhat random looking initial data if the array is created in an area of memory with non-zero data present.

With `dtype='U3'`, the output of your code then becomes:

```
array(['NW', 'NE', 'SSW', 'N'], dtype='<U3')
```